# SwiftUI - List items are not deselected

Tags: list, swiftui

I recently switched to Xcode 12/iOS 14, I noticed that my `List` selections are no longer deselected when navigating to a new view and then back. Upon returning, the list item that was selected is still highlighted. As far as I know there isn't a deselectRowAtIndexPath option for SwiftUI. I even tried resigning the first responder but that did nothing.

```
let someArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    
var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
      VStack {
         Text("zero")
         List(someArray, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(
               destination: Text(item)) {
                  Text(item)
               }
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant code?

Comment: I remember this being a bug last year, which I don't know if it ever went away completely. Try both a real device, and the simulator.

Comment: I discovered that stripping the code back to just a List allowed it to work as expected. But when I put it in a VStack with another view, it stopped deselecting.

Comment: any resolution on this question?

Comment: The problem can still be reproduced on an iOS 14.5 Simulator and iOS 14.6 device: as soon as an element is put in front of the List, the selection  persists when navigating back. But it is fixed on iOS 15 (currently in beta)

Answer (score 1):

Put .id(UUID()) on your List. This will always reload the list and remove the selection.

Comment: I tried adding .id(UUID()) at the end of the List in the example above - it did not work. But I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a UUID to the actual NavigationLink, not the list. The list will use your newly added UUID to identify which link to deselect.